# Orthogonal Eigen-Basis Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

In any euclidean space, will the eigenvectors be always orthogonal ?

As a result of spectral theorem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an arbitrary operator, no.  For instance, on finite dimensional spaces, an operator is unitarily diagonalizable (i.e. has orthonormal eigenvectors) if and only if it is normal, that is it commutes with its adjoint.  Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem).

Comment: Aren't all normal matrices either hermitian or skew-hermitian ?

Comment: @user107915 No. Unitary matrices are also normal, and so are lots of other examples.